# Finding object id's from unordered Google API responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, asynchronous

I'm writing a backend API in Node.js, however the coolest feature of it, **async functions** are now challenging me with a new problem.

I have a list of objects called **Person** with the information of **ID, Latitude, Longitude**. And what I simply want to do is sort them according to their distance to a certain point *(Let's say Point **A**)*.

When I would like to loop through each object, make a request, (I'm using module **request**. [Can be checked in here](https://github.com/mikeal/request)). However due to it's nature Node first **loops through**  all the objects, sends requests, and doesn't wait for the reply. So when the reply comes I cannot understand which reply is for which person. Even though it list's their ID in correct order when I check through Redis I see that responses of the Google API request's are not ordered. Here is my code for a better understanding;

```
for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++){

    console.log("the iteration time: "+i);
    tempObject = JSON.parse(result[i]);

    console.log("\n I make the request for key: "+tempObject.ID);
    request('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='+tempObject.lat+
    ','+tempObject.lon+'&destination=' + targetLatitude + ',' + targetLongitude 
    + '&sensor=false', 
    function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            console.log("Lat: "+tempObject.lat);
            console.log("Lon: "+tempObject.lon);

            console.log("key: "+list[counter]);
            tempObj = JSON.parse(body);

            counter++; //For loop end check

            console.log("i: "+i);


            duration = tempObj.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value;


            console.log("Duration: "+tempObj.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value+"\n");

            if(counter == result.length){
                //end loop
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I would like to state **I do not have any trouble with my code**. I just cannot find the solution for this problem: How can I get the id's of my Person list, when responses from Google Maps Direction API **does not come ordered**. Loop makes the requests one by one for each Person object in list, however the responses from Google are not in order **thus I cannot obtain their ID's**.

I even thought like putting the objects in a list, and later by checking the starting point lat and long in the API response, comparing them with the Person in the list, I can identify whose response came first, but that did not work out as well. Any suggestions?

**PS:**  If you see word "key" it means id of the user. I'm using Redis so I tend to use "key" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function closure to associate the request with the response.

Example using geocoded addresses:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_geocoder_multiplePoints.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could please explain a bit in detail?